# Sbt package manager not resolving at Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, playframework-2.0, bonecp

Hi guys im trying to add a new bonecp version to my play framework 2.0.4 app at heroku,
but im getting

```
[info] downloading http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/jolbox/bonecp/0.8.0-rc2-SNAPSHOT/bonecp-0.8.0-rc2-20130128.135547-1.jar ...
       [info]   [SUCCESSFUL ] com.jolbox#bonecp;0.8.0-rc2-SNAPSHOT!bonecp.jar(bundle) (367ms)
       [warn]   [NOT FOUND  ] com.google.guava#guava;13.0.1!guava.jar (10ms)
       [warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
       [warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/google/guava/guava/13.0.1/guava-13.0.1.jar
       [info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.2/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar ...
       [info]   [SUCCESSFUL ] org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.2!slf4j-api.jar (60ms)
       [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
       [warn]   ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
       [warn]   :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
       [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
       [warn]   :: com.google.guava#guava;13.0.1!guava.jar
       [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
       [error] {file:/tmp/build_16vgl6xi6x33j/}theapp/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: download failed: com.google.guava#guava;13.0.1!guava.jar
       [error] Total time: 8 s, completed Apr 19, 2013 10:37:35 AM
 !     Failed to build app with sbt
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.x - java app
```

It can't seem to find google guava at typesafe.

I works locally but not at heroku.
Something is probably wrong with the resolvers but i don't know what.

Here is my Build.scala configuration:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
                "com.google.api.client" % "google-api-data-youtube-v2" % "1.0.6-alpha",
                "com.google.gdata" % "core" % "1.47.1",
                "org.apache.commons" % "commons-io" % "1.3.2",
                "org.reflections" % "reflections" % "0.9.8",
                "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.24",
                "org.scribe" % "scribe" % "1.3.2",
                "com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached" % "0.2.3-SNAPSHOT",
                "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.3.11",
                "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.2.2",
                "com.rabbitmq" % "amqp-client" % "2.8.7",
                "com.google.javascript" % "closure-compiler" % "rr2079.1",
                "com.restfb" % "restfb" % "1.6.11",
                "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.0.4",
                "com.jolbox" % "bonecp" % "0.8.0-rc2-SNAPSHOT"
    )

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
    resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots Repository" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public",
    resolvers += "Spy Repository" at "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2" // required to resolve `spymemcached`, the plugin's dependency.
)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

it could be fixed now. it failed on me a few hours ago but now it works